# How can I sync data Magento to ExactTarget?

Tags: marketing-cloud, data

I would like to simplify moving people who register on my Magento websites into ExactTarget.

Currently, we use Magento's built-in forms to collect information.  Export it, edit it, and import into ExactTarget.

I've explored building embedded ET forms, but the error handling component is eluding me (I can get people to an error page, but displaying the specifics of the error is beyond me, a case where the tutorials seem to be aimed at people who already understand the system).

Are there integration tool, outside apps, or other resources that would help me make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

1. Use the SFMC [**SOAP**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/web_service_guide.htm) or [**REST**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm) API to make an API call to add the subscriber in SFMC.   [**Here's**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/web_service_guide.htm) the Web Service guide. (complex, very flexible)
2. Set up a process on the Magento side that pushes an export file to your SFMC FTP share, which could [**trigger an import**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en-US/documentation/automation_studio/triggered_automations/) on the SFMC side. (moderate complexity, very stable)
3. You can use [**Web Collect**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/web_collect/) form post to add a subscriber (simple, limited flexibility).

Answer (score 0):

Try contacting the team at Windsor Circle for their [**Magento app on HubExchange**](https://hubexchange.s1.marketingcloudapps.com/listing/windsor-circle/magento-ecommerce-connector).

The app integration primarily moves ecommerce datasets into Lists and Data Extensions, but the integration should be able to support your Magento web collect needs.